# CDO selling or buying credit protection?

Tags: credit-risk, cdo

I think there is an error in the [Meissner text](http://ca.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-111879690X.html) - Correlation Risk Modeling and Management and can't find an errata for this text to verify.

On page 19 the foot note reads:

> 10. Shorting the equity tranche means being short credit protection or selling credit protection, which means receiving the (high) equity
>       tranche contract spread

In the context, he is talking about CDOs, which makes me think this is incorrect. In a CDO, doesn't being ***short*** a tranche ***buy credit protection*** and ***investing*** in the tranche (long) is to ***sell credit protection***?

When you invest in one of the tranches of a CDO, you are exposed to credit risk which is why you are compensated by a spread right ?

Comment: In most of the case, a CDO is synthetic. That is, we do not invest in the tranche directly, but only long or short the credit protection on the tranches.

Answer (score 1):

investor interest in cash cdo tranches is driven by gaining [leveraged] credit exposure; in cash cdo investor goes long credit exposure and statement "going long tranche implies short exposure (i.e. buy credit protection)" is questionable.

synthetic: Entity which issues cdo may sell cds and collect premiums; these premiums are further distributed to pay investors in cdo tranches - effectively investors are going short cds (long credit exposure) and collect coupons for doing so. Going long the tranche is effectively long credit exposure (short cds); and going short the tranche is effectively short credit exposure (buy cds).

credit protection = short credit exposure

short (credit protection) = short (short credit exposure) = long credit exposure

hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I can't follow what you're trying to say.

Comment: i wanted to say shorting the tranche mean short expsure (effectively long protection and the author's statement seems incorrect. Moreover on the same page 19-20 author's sentences
`Hedge funds had shorted the equity tranche collect the high equity tranche spread. They had then presumably hedged the risk by going long the mezzanine tranche.` seems to be missing the point, as the **big** trade was long equity tranche and short mezzanine.

Comment: and the way hedge fund were achieving such exposure was via _short protection_ on equity tranche (not _short the tranche_) and buy protection on mezz. For more info about equity vs mezz trade have a look [here, page 50](http://www.sps.ed.ac.uk/__data/assets/pdf_file/0003/84243/Gaussian14.pdf) and [here](http://www.tavakolistructuredfinance.com/cash-flows-synthetic-cdo/)